# App getting crash when trying to capture image to upload in ionic3 In some devices (RedMi 6A)

Tags: angular, ionic3

```
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
    // Special handling for Android library

    console.log(imagePath);

    let currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/'));
    let correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName(x), x);

    /* localStorage.setItem("file_no",'1'); */
    this.upImages[x] = currentName;
    this.file_no = this.file_no + 1;

}, (err) => {
    this.presentToast('Error while selecting image.');
});
```

Comment: When we select camera , camera opening successfully but when we click on capture button app in background getting closed without showing any error message